# How do I fix order item details in email template?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, order-email

We have installed v1.9.1.0 rwd theme on this site. The order email is doing something wierd on one of our sites. The item details are supposed to be printing acroos the whole width of the page. I checked the email-inline.css and the 'items' class width is 100%, but it appears to be around 40% width. I cannot figure out what to edit to fix this. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding this line of code to the email templates in System > Transactional Emails.

{{var non_inline_styles}}

http://www.screencast.com/t/mKx8SXeP

http://www.screencast.com/t/IgyHzjE2wYh

Refer to Responsive Email Developer's Guide for Magento EE 1.14.1 and Magento CE 1.9.1
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_responsive_emails.html?_ga=1.9964213.126657466.1466709202